# Batch file to rename files in folder if the filename has (-*)

Tags: vbscript

I'm doing an exercise on batch files. However I am still new to scripts. I want it to run on older Windows as much as Windows 10 so basically if the code is formatted in CMD. I still don't understand what are batch files and simple scripts.

It's just a simple script that takes the current directory where the script file is located and run through the files. Some files has `-1212.txt` for example `File-1.txt`.

I would like to remove the `-1` or whatever number is after the name. I know I need to loop though every char and find (-) then remove whats after that character.

This is what I tried

```
Set objFso = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)

Set Folder = %~dp0

For Each File In Folder.Files

    sNewFile = File.Name


    sNewFile = rename "-*.*"

    if (*****) then

        File......

    end if

Next
```

Just don't know how to get this working, could you please explain your code

Comment: this is VBS and not a batch. Both are [scripting languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)

Comment: You need to scrap what you have and start over. The majority of the code you've provided is VBScript, but you're trying to intermingle batch commands into ti (which is not possible) randomly. Review your course materials or notes, decide what language you're going to use and then stick to it, and try again to complete your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

With VBScript, something like this should work:

```
Dim fso
Dim file
Dim folder
Dim sNewName
Dim iIndex

' Create File System Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Get current folder
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(".\")

For Each file In folder.Files

    iIndex = InStr(1, file.Name, "-")
    If iIndex > 0 Then

        ' Remove characters
        sNewName = Left(file.Name, iIndex - 1) & Mid(file.Name, iIndex + 2)

        file.Name = sNewName

    End If

Next
```